# Can't change a for loop to forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach

I'm trying to change this one:

```
const removeElements = (arr, callback) => {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    callback(arr[i], arr);
  }
  return arr;
};
```

To a forEach like this:

```
const removeWithForEach = (arr, callback) => {
  arr.forEach(callback(arr.value, arr));
};
```

But it's not working. Would you guys help?

Comment: Please define "_it's not working._"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently calling the `callback` immediately, before `forEach` is invoked. Pass a function *reference* to `forEach` instead:

```
const removeWithForEach = (arr, callback) => {
  arr.forEach((value) => {
    callback(value, arr);
  });
  return arr;
};
```

(though it would make more sense just to use `Array.prototype.forEach` instead of `removeWithForEach`)

Answer (score 1):

Why not change the signature of `callback` to

```
const callback = (element, index, array) => { /* code */ };
//                         ^^^^^^ add this parameter
```

and use the calback directly ind [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
const removeWithForEach = (arr, callback) => arr.forEach(callback);
```